# How do Muslim women have personal freedom when their movement is restricted by their guardian?

Tags: women, wali, freedom

According to Islam, female children (even adult/unmarried) enjoy personal freedom, individual identity, inheritance, freedom of choice and right to health and education. But what do terms like "personal freedom and freedom of choice" mean if she always have to take permission from father to move?  Like to go to meet friend, bank or need any beauty or medical treatment. I'm over 30 years old, but cannot enjoy rights like freedom of movement to meet anybody I wish. How can I choose a spouse just by sitting at home and not executing my right of choice?

Comment: @infatuated asking why the restrictions exist is the same as asking about the reason for them, or, as you put it, the "wisdom behind the restrictions". The question is perfectly valid, on the one hand, she is supposed to have personal freedom, but on the other hand, she is forced to ask her guardian (father or husband, i.e. the male that "owns" her) for permission in whatever she does. How does that coexist with her supposed personal freedom?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to partly understand that the answer is embedded in your question. The answer simply is: "They don't." You have to choose between not having your personal freedom and breaking up from your guardian. Legally you are an adult and have every right to decide about your own life. And you can still be a good muslim, as you also seem to already understand.

Answer (score -2):

Personal and freedom of choice are indeed meaningless if you have to take permission from someone else for every trivial thing, especially if you are above 18 -20 years of age.
In such a case you are being duped by an illusion of freedom.

On a more personal front - if you are over 30 you can do whatever you want with your life. A parent is only responsible for a child not a mature adult.

Comment: Freedom is *always* an illusion! Only God can be truly free!